# Availability of machine-readable OCC Infomemos?

Tags: data

Does anyone know of a source of machine-readable (XML,etc) OCC Infomemos? The PDF files available below contain all the information I want, but are a pain to parse.

http://www.optionsclearing.com/market-data/infomemos/infomemos1.jsp

Answer (score 1):

I do not. But I do know how to parse these specific pdfs quite easily.

Using the open source pdftotext tool ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext ).

The table data in the output text file will always (testing the types of the values should ensure that everything is working as expected in case of changes) begin after the line ExDate and ends before DISCLAIMER, with a blank line occuring between each value

(regular expression to grab text between ExData\n\n, \n\nDISCLAIMER, and you have a plain text double-newline delimited representation of the data).